# what happens when we "install" pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

i thought tools like opencv or pytorch are just some codes for developer to import and use the functions of them,in this degree, we just need to copy the source , of course ,things definately are not that straight-forward. So what extra operation do we need to use the tools(install them),and why?

Comment: OpenCV and Pytorch aren't just written in Python. Both have C components which need to be compiled and linked so they are available in Python. Try using a package manager like pipenv or anaconda to avoid having to finagle with pip yourself.

Comment: Whats the problem, Why do you ask? Is it because you are having issues installing? If so can you give more details?

Comment: @Paul Rooney no other issues,just like use 'cd **/**' everyday and all  of a sudden  want to know what is 'cd' short for  :)

Comment: @ Bailey Parker c components makes sense,thank you~